# Multi-variable declaration and initialization

Tags: abap

Let's say I have a method with a few import parameters:

```
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------
*"  IMPORTING
*"     VALUE(iv_xx)  TYPE  xx
*"     VALUE(iv_xxx) TYPE  xxx
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I don't want to work with them directly as I can not change their values when debugging inside the method and for probably many more reasons. Therefore I declare new variables that I assign the import values to. There are many ways to do this...

I started out like this:

```
DATA lv_xx  TYPE xx.
DATA lv_xxx TYPE xxx.

lv_xx  = iv_xx.
lv_xxx = iv_xxx.
```

Went on to:

```
DATA:
  lv_xx  TYPE xx,
  lv_xxx TYPE xxx.

lv_xx  = iv_xx.
lv_xxx = iv_xxx.
```

Evolved to:

```
DATA:
  lv_xx  LIKE iv_xx,
  lv_xxx LIKE iv_xxx.

lv_xx  = iv_xx.
lv_xxx = iv_xxx.
```

And recently found an even lazier way:

```
DATA(lv_xx)  = iv_xx.
DATA(lv_xxx) = iv_xxx.
```

Now I wonder:
**Can I take it one step further and eliminate the "DATA(...)" duplication somehow?**
I'm looking for something like

```
DATA( 
 lv_xx  = iv_xx
 lv_xxx = iv_xxx
).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see that your parameters are **passed by value**, so a copy is implicitly done by the kernel, no need to use auxiliary variables. You can also change these passed-by-value parameters while debugging (maybe there was a bug in the debugger some time ago, but it isn't there any more).

So, you might have a problem only with parameters **passed by reference**, because they are assigned a "read-only" flag.

Anyway, to answer your question, one possibility is to use a macro :

```
CLASS ltc_main DEFINITION FOR TESTING DURATION SHORT RISK LEVEL HARMLESS
      INHERITING FROM cl_aunit_assert.
  PRIVATE SECTION.
    METHODS test FOR TESTING.
    METHODS test2
      IMPORTING
        VALUE(iv_xx)  TYPE  i
        VALUE(iv_xxx) TYPE  i.
ENDCLASS.
CLASS ltc_main IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD test2.

    DEFINE mac_data.
      DATA(&1) &2 &3.
    END-OF-DEFINITION.

    mac_data :
      lv_xx  = iv_xx,
      lv_xxx = iv_xxx.

    assert_equals( act = lv_xx exp = 5 ).
    assert_equals( act = lv_xxx exp = 9 ).
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD test.
    test2( iv_xx = 5 iv_xxx = 9 ).
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
```

But personally, I wouldn't use a macro, I'd declare every auxiliary variable like `DATA(lv_xx) = iv_xx`.

Comment: oh gosh, I just copied that first bit from somewhere - didn't know that `VALUE()` changes everything. But this is very informative - thx - so I guess the answer is there's no built-in way

Comment: yep, can't do better than repeating `DATA(lv_xx) = iv_xx.` for each variable

Comment: don't recommend macros, they can't be debugged, and have several other problems. They should have never existed.

Comment: Agree. Inventive but somehow over the top. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
TYPES:
  BEGIN OF input_type,
    xx  TYPE xx,
    xxx TYPE xxx,
  END OF input_type.

DATA(input) = VALUE input_type( xx  = iv_xx
                                xxx = iv_xxx ).
```

Answer (score 1):

And the ultimate nonsense. ;-)

```
DEFINE mac_data.
  DATA(lv_&1) = iv_&2.
END-OF-DEFINITION.

mac_data : xx, xxx.
```